# If $A$ and $B$ are convex and disjoint then there exist a continuous linear function such that $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are dijoint.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

This looks similar to the hyperplane Hahn-Banach separation theorem except that we may have empty interior. I want to know if the following is true.

> Let $X$ be a real locally convex topological vector space and let $A$ and $B$ be convex disjoint subsets, then there exists a continuous linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(A)\cap f(B)$ are disjoint.

I would be interested in any approach to this problem or in any counter example.

Comment: What about $A=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: (x\leq 0 \text{ and } y=0),\text{ or }  y>0\}$ (in other words, $A$ is the upper half plane with "half" of its boundary added), with $B=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$? You can also build bounded examples.

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much. What about the case when $B=\{ b\}$ ? I am interested in that in order to prove (in a different way than the one I saw) the fact that $x$ is an extreme point of $X$ if and only if $\delta_x$ is the only measure representing $x$. The idea is to take $A=X\setminus \{ x\}$ and $B=\{x\}$ and then generate the desired $f$ as described in the question, then look at sets of the form $\mu(X\cap f^{-1}([f(x)-1/n,f(x)+1/n]))$ for some measure $\mu$ and show that either $\mu(f)\neq f(x)$ or $\mu=\delta_x$.

Comment: Actually I now realize that your example is also a counter example for what I just said. Indeed $(0,0)$ is an extreme point  of your first set, and there is no separation.

Comment: Typically, you need some closedness assumptions on $A$ and $B$.